# How do I conditionally add an attribute to a Semantic UI React element?

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using Semantic UI React for a basic front end.

I'm using the `Dimmer` module which I want to conditionally apply the `active` attribute to, depending on whether the page is currently loading.

Whether the page is loading or not is indicated by a state variable. The below *does* seem to work, but it outputs a warning, which I'd like to remove.

```
<Dimmer active={this.state.isLoading} inverted>
  <Loader inverted></Loader>
</Dimmer>
```

The `isLoading` variable is a boolean:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      ...
```

The console warning is as follows:

```
warning.js:33 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `active`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: active="true" or active={value.toString()}.
    in div (created by DimmerDimmable)
    in DimmerDimmable (at explore.js:110)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (at explore.js:102)
    in div (at Layout.js:7)
    in Unknown (at explore.js:101)
    in ExploreBounty (created by App)
    in Container (created by App)
    in App
    in ErrorBoundary
```

Changing the boolean value of `true` to a string results in the following contradictory warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `active` of type `string` supplied to `Dimmer`, expected `boolean`.
    in Dimmer (at explore.js:111)
    in ExploreBounty (created by App)
    in Container (created by App)
    in App
    in ErrorBoundary
```

**Again, the page works with the boolean value, but I want to get rid of the warning. How do I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error here, the first error is not coming from your `<Dimmer>` component, it is coming from the `<Dimmer.Dimmable>` component.

On the `<Dimmer>` the `active` prop is indeed boolean, so you should continue to pass it there as a boolean from state.

On the `<Dimmer.Dimmable>` component, there is no `active` prop. That is why you are getting a warning. My guess is that you are passing `active={this.state.isLoading}` on both your Dimmer and Dimmer.Dimmable. If you use the `dimmed` component on the Dimmer.Dimmable I think that will solve your issue.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks!